# serializer.is_valid returns false with an error that the field is required even though I am passing it

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am building a serializer so that if I post using the following command
`curl -d '{"food": "test", "portion": 12}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/food` it will save to the db. However my problem is `serializer.is_valid()` returns false with an error that the field "food" is required even though I am passing it.
I am unable to change the curl command so how can I make it work?
Any help is appreciated.

views.py

```
class FoodAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.body)
        except:
            return Response({"message": "ERROR DETECT"})
        serializer = FoodSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            //save 
        else:
            print(serializer.errors)//{'food': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}
            return Response({'message': 'ERROR DETECT'})
```

serializer.py

```
class FoodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["food", "portion"]
```

Output

```
FoodSerializer(data=<QueryDict: {'{"food": "test", "portion": 12}': ['']}>):
    food = CharField(max_length=8)
    portion = IntegerField(required=False)
```

Comment: Why are you not able to change the curl command? Can you try this curl command: ```curl -X POST -d "food=test&portion=12" http://127.0.0.1:8000/food```

Comment: For test purposes unfortunately I cannot change the curl command. So that's not an option.

Comment: But does this command work or not: ```curl -X POST -d "food=test&portion=12" http://127.0.0.1:8000/food```?

Comment: @AyushGupta I tried but it does not work...

Comment: Can you provide your full ```views.py```, ```serializers.py```? And what is ```LOG```?

Comment: @AyushGupta I provided full views.py and serializers,py. Log is the output when run

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235722/discussion-between-ayush-gupta-and-satsuki).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work with a JSON blob, you need to process `data`, not `request.data` since `request.data` works as if you pass the data with a www-form-urlencode:

```
class FoodAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.body)
        except:
            return Response({"message": "ERROR DETECT"})
        #      use data, not request.data ↓
        serializer = FoodSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
        else:
            print(serializer.errors)
            return Response({'message': 'ERROR DETECT'})
```

You furthermore should make a POST request and use `application/json` as content type, and thus test this with:

```
#        ↓ POST request            ↓ JSON content type
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"food": "test", "portion": 12}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/food
```